# Player code for live dynamic bitrate switching on Wowza

Tags: streaming, live, wowza

I'm using http://flowplayer.org/plugins/streaming/bwcheck.html for dynamic bitrate switching on VoD without any problem but I can't get flowplayer or jwplayer working with live streams.

Does anyone have any foolproof code examples please for ANY player working with Wowza?

Edit:

I add live: true and change the stream names to stream_1 etc in the example above but just get a stream doesn't exist error.

Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain the exact issue you're having with jwplayer/flowplayer?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways of doing this in JWplayer. One is client-side with levels:

```
<div id="container">Loading the player...</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("container").setup({
        flashplayer: "/jwplayer/player.swf",
            height: 270,
            width: 480,
            image: "/thumbs/video.jpg",
            levels: [
                { bitrate: 300, file: "videos/video_300k.mp4", width: 320 },
                { bitrate: 600, file: "videos/video_600k.mp4", width: 480 },
                { bitrate: 900, file: "videos/video_900k.mp4", width: 720 }
            ],
            provider: "rtmp",
            streamer: "rtmp://rtmp.example.com/application/"
    });
</script>
```

The other is using a server-side RSS. As of Patch 8, Wowza V3 will generate an RSS file based on a smil file (like you'd use for adaptive bitrate switching for iOS) or an ngrp (generated by the Wowza V3 transcoder). The URLs you'd use are:

```
http://[wowza-ip-address]:1935/[application]/smil:[streamName].smil/jwplayer.rss - JWPlayer adaptive streaming

http://[wowza-ip-address]:1935/[application]/ngrp:[streamName]/jwplayer.rss - JWPlayer adaptive streaming
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Should point out here that as of JWPlayer V6, the server-side playlist  no longer uses RSS and will take standard SMIL output. Wowza 3.5 will provide this as jwplayer.smil.